# I am planning to write stories - But how do I publish and sell them?

Tags: publishing, editing, planning

I'm planning to write stories. However I am not an expert in writing or phrasing english sentences.

Is there any website which can fix the writing and publish the stories in my name and we can sell it by paying royalty to them? Basically all publishing and fixing the grammar should be done by them.

Comment: Type "self-publish" into your browser and respond to one of the ads. Caveat: they usually charge per correction; it can cost $1000s for ESL authors. Self-publishing requires you to promote yourself.

Comment: This might actually be better split into multiple questions. For the part of "fixing the grammar", see [How do I find an affordable editor?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/2529/2533) which this *just might* be a duplicate of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am no expert in self publishing, but I have looked into it, so maybe I can help a bit.

I don't know of a "one stop shop" for book editing, formatting, and publishing. However, here is a basic outline of the self publishing process.

First, you need to write your book. This is difficult (and emotionally painful).

Next, you are going to need to get edited. You can search the internet for book editor or go to a website specifically for freelancers. There is also software available for use. For grammar you can check out [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/). For style you can check out [AutoCrit](https://www.autocrit.com/) or [Pro Writing Aid](https://prowritingaid.com/). I personally use AutoCrit. I have never used Pro Writing Aid, but from what I've heard, AutoCrit is better and easier to use, but much more expensive.

Next you're going to need long into the layout and book cover. Again, Google or Bing is your friend here for finding someone to use.

Now you can probably start looking at self publishing. [IngramSpark](http://www.ingramspark.com/) is a print on demand service that also helps with ebook distribution. [CreateSpace](https://www.createspace.com/) is similar. It is owned by Amazon, is cheaper, and lower quality from what I hear. Those are good options if you want a physical copy. You can also look into ebooks only.

That is a **very basic** outline. There are some smaller details you will need to look into for actually submitting your book. [Here](http://www.ingramspark.com/plan-your-book/novels) is IngramSpark's page for publishing with them and the details related to it.

Wherever you choose to self publish, be sure check that you have everything ready before you submit.

Lastly, [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Self-Publish-a-Book) is a basic look at self publishing.